# How can I add and sort MySQL results by ID (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, sum

I'm trying to write some code in PHP that will allow me to get the top 10 pages on my site over the last week, month, year, etc.  Right now, page views per day are stored in a a table.  Each row contains the page ID, the unix time stamp for 0:00 of that day and the number of pageviews that day.

So to accomplish what I want, I need to select all of the rows in this table (for my given time frame) and then add up the number of pageviews for each row with the same page id and then sort it high to low.  I can't think of a way of doing this that isn't insanely complicated with tons of loops.  Anyone have some ideas for me?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what you've written so far?

Comment: Learn  DAY, MONTH, YEAR, GROUP BY, COUNT and ORDER BY functions off MYSQL

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way is probably to simply do the query for each time period you want

```
SELECT page_id, SUM(pageviews)
FROM table
WHERE
time BETWEEN yourstarttime AND NOW();
GROUP BY page_id
ORDER BY SUM(pageviews);
```

`yourstarttime` for, say, the last year would be `DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)` to get all the counts in the last year.

Comment: I do believe you will need the `SUM()` of `pageviews` and not the `COUNT()`, since each row contains the number of page views for that day.

Comment: @Linger Ack. Well spotted. Fixing.

Comment: Why Simple is not always best.. this can be hard on large tables (and web traffic tables can and will be large) even with an covering index it triggers the need for an temporary table and filesort (quicksort) pass. check http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/018c69/1 .. problem is the combination off  GROUP BY page_id/ORDER BY SUM(pageviews) better option can be an derived table

Comment: @RaymondNijland So would you suggest doing the ordering in PHP?

Comment: @Jim no not in PHP but an derived table isn't an very good option here also because the grouping is offcource always needed on page_id (i think i need some coffee) even when you use an derived table (read subquery within the FROM).. topicstater likly more needs an divide and conquer strategy to keep performance but i can tell now because i've didn't see an example of structure or data..

Comment: @jim iam not sure on how to interprent this http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/580fe/27 because it looks like that the derived table query only needs to use (estimate off) 4 records for "Using temporary; Using filesort" because <derived2> points to the second row what uses (estimate off) 8 records from an covering index.. if so this means that the derived table could be 50% more efficient..

Answer (score 0):

You could use the MySQL date functions to pull out the part of the date you care about, and group by that.

For example, if you were handling it by week you could use the week() function http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week to turn the timestamp into a week, then your hits from each week would be grouped and you could sort descending to find the top 10.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [DATE_SUB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-sub)

```
SELECT *
FROM `yourTable`
WHERE `some_time` < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK);
```

(With the "2 WEEK" being what you would need).